# How to create an exception when a double is Null/Empty in C#?

Tags: c#, double

I am creating blackjack in C#. When the game starts, my code asks the user to "Please, make a bet." However, the user may just click "enter", and the application will crash. I tried making an exception:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Please, make a bet");
        bet = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        try
        {
            bet = 0;
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have to bet in order to play");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have to bet in order to play");
        }
```

However, it does not seem to be working and my application crashes nonetheless. The bet variable is a double, and therefore I cannot use `if(double.IsNullOrEmpty(bet)){//Something};` the same way that I would if it was a string. `double.IsNan(bet)` also does not work as a condition. So, how do I make an exception when the double is null/empty?

Comment: You'll want to use `double.TryParse` to determine if they did not enter anything or if the value they entered is not a number. Or capture the result of `Console.ReadLine` and check what it is before attempting to convert it.

Comment: Dont use exceptions to control program flow - there is nothing at all exceptional about bad user input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line which throws the exception, in this case `bet = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())` must be inside the `try` block in order for the exception to be caught.

```
try
{
   bet = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (System.FormatException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("You have to make a bet.");
}
catch (Exception)
{
   Console.WriteLine("You have to make a bet.");
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) to parse the user's input.

Maybe something like...

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your bet.");
while (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out bet))
{
   Console.WriteLine("You have to make a bet.");
}
```

Comment: Could you also please explain what the second code does? Thank you.

Comment: `Double.TryParse` simply takes a `string` and tries to parse it as a `double`. If successful, it will return `true` and the parsed value will be placed into the `out` parameter passed in as the second parameter. The `while` loop will continue to execute until `double.TryParse` is successful, that way the user is continually asked for a bet until they enter a value that parses to a `double`. Be aware that once you reach that loop, you cannot exit the program without breaking, E.G. `CTRL+C`, or entering a value that parses to a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Better not use *exceptions* (which are for *exceptional* behavior) here, but `TryParse`:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Please, make a bet");

  // keep asking user while
  //  1. bet is not a valid floating point
  //  2. bet is negative
  //  3. bet is too high 
  while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out bet) || bet < 0 || bet > 1e100) {
    Console.WriteLine("You have to make a bet.");
  }

  // from now on bet is a valid double value in [0..1e100] range
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not checking if is null or not

```
if(bet == null){
Console.WriteLine("You have to make a bet");
}else{
Console.WriteLine("That");
}
```

Comment: `bet` is a `double` so comparing it to an empty string will not even compile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but since variable bet is a double, it is impossible to make `bet == ""` a condition.

Comment: No, a `double` cannot be equal to `null` either.  Besides the error happens during the `Convert.ToDouble` before anything is even assigned to `bet`.

Comment: Try Double and not double

Comment: `double` is just an alias for `Double`, so they are the same thing in C#.  `double?` would be the type that can be a `double` or `null`.

Comment: not the same i think, but well sorry try something because i search